# How to generate a dataset for question answering from books (like Facebook's bAbI)?

Tags: natural-language-processing, training, datasets, chat-bots, question-answering

I wanted to train a chatbot for answering questions from books. I am trying to use [Dynamic Memory Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07285) to do so.

How can I generate a data set, as Facebook did in the case of [bAbI tasks](https://research.fb.com/downloads/babi/), so that it can tackle a variety of questions on the data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/facebook/bAbI-tasks#id17) repository maintained by Facebook AI Research talks about how they went about generating QA from stories.

In essence, they try to simulate how a reader reads a story. They also keep track about the knowledge the reader is assimilating when reading. Then they frame a question based on the knowledge assimilated, in order to asses if the reader can perform logical inference given what knowledge is present with him.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about "generating" in the sense of generative models , it is pretty tough. since we are still far beyond understanding the actual structure of question-answering.

And even state of the art methods for question answering are also not able to score well on datasets like [babi](http://classif.ai/dataset/babi/) , mostly 16 out of 20 tasks can be solved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering @thecomplexitytheorist. I wanted to create BaBI like tasks from a custom dataset - like a book. So it was not exactly like fully generating from scratch.